# Adding interactive text

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, interactive

I have two `text` style cells as shown in the picture (second one is hidden). Is it possible to add an interactive button so that if someone clicks on that button/text then the second cell's can be toggled between `open` and `hidden`?

Alternatively, it is also fine if a mouse-over on a button/text brings up a message saying that there is a hidden cell nearby but I would really prefer to have the toggle thing if it is possible in `Mathematica`.

Desired Output :- When someone clicks on `expand the cell below` then the hidden cell is set to `open` and when it is clicked again then the cell is again `hidden`.

[image: img]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a button like this:

`Button["Toggle cell below", 
 SetOptions[NextCell[], 
  CellOpen -> ! CurrentValue[NextCell[], CellOpen]]]`

Comment: You could also make the button label dynamic:  `Button[Dynamic[If[CurrentValue[NextCell[], CellOpen],
   "Less", "More"]], 
 SetOptions[NextCell[], 
  CellOpen -> ! CurrentValue[NextCell[], CellOpen]]]`

Comment: Both of these work very well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the option `"ShowGroupOpener"` to `True` for the first cell of a cell group to add an `Opener` to open/close the cell groups. Alternatively, set the option `"WholeCellGroupOpener"` to `True` to make the whole cell a behave like a toggler button.

You can do this in two ways:

**Manually:** Right-click the cell bracket and select `Properties` to    open the
    `Option Inspector` notebook. Click`Cell Options >> Display Options` and change the setting for `"ShowGroupOpener"`.

[image]

**Programatically:** In the first cell of the notebook, using some identifying text  for the cells to be modified (`"comments"` in the example below), execute

```
SetOptions[NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "comments", All], 
 "ShowGroupOpener" -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. I hope you don't mind that I keep the other answer as the accepted one because that was posted earlier and the contributor is new.